# MySQL incorrect order by with UTF8 characters

Tags: mysql, utf-8

I have a table with field `name`, which is in `utf8_general_ci`. When I run this query `SELECT name FROM users ORDER BY name ASC` I got some strange results. After letter 'S' comes special letter 'Š', which is correct, but after 'Š' comes more letters 'S', which should be before that. Other than that the results are fine. Why is this ordering like this and how should I fix it?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you post some of the sample data as well.

Answer (score 1):

The `utf8_general_ci` collation considers all variations of a letter equal. You have to use a binary collation (`utf8_bin`) or a collation based on a national standard (such as `utf8_czech_ci`) if you want to treat S and Š as distinct letters.

Comment: I used utf8_bin, but it separates upper case letters from lower case and that's not what I need. National standards won't work because it is an international website.

Comment: An international user would expect to find all accented variations of letters together, so that Š-words are mixed with S-words. If you start going down that path you'll find that you'll also have to separate N and Ñ, sort Ä after Z, etc... If the *only* variation from the generic order is separating S and Š you can define a collation of your own, but it's a bit a hassle: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/adding-collation.html